# Tensorflow with GPU and CUDA v5.5

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use the GPU enabled version of Tensorflow. I read that it works best with CUDA 7.5 but the server that I am using has CUDA version 5.5 installed.

Can I configure Tensorflow with CUDA 5.5? If yes, how? I have installed tensorflow in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the installation doc:

> In order to build or run TensorFlow with GPU support, both NVIDIA's Cuda Toolkit (>= 7.0) and cuDNN (>= v2) need to be installed.

If you don't install from source, you will need to use version 7.5.

---

Also make sure that you have a compatible GPU:

> TensorFlow GPU support requires having a GPU card with NVidia Compute Capability >= 3.0. Supported cards include but are not limited to:
>
> - NVidia Titan
> - NVidia Titan X
> - NVidia K20
> - NVidia K40